# Anonymous function and loop issue

Tags: php, loops, while-loop, anonymous-function

See Anonymous function below, I do not want go to next `for` loop iteration until `$Connected` is 0

It did not work how it should be...  what is the solution to fix this?

```
 $Client = new Client();

for ($i = 1; $i <= 5; $i++) {

 $result = $Client->Action(rand(1,1000));

 if ($result->isSuccess()) {
     $Connected = 1;
  }

  // Stay in the loop until 'HangupEvent' received
  while ($Connected) {
    $Client->EventListener(function (EventMessage $event) {
        if ($event instanceof HangupEvent) {
            // Received Hangup Event - let terminate this while loop ..
            $Connected = 0;
         }
    });

   // If  $Connected = 0; then go to next `for` loop iteration
  }

}
```

Comment: Hmm, have you read the documentation (example 3)? http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php. It's shown there...  but whether this is the solution to your problem, I don't know... you will add a million event handlers to the client...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to pass the $Connected variable to your function with `use`

```
$Client->EventListener(function (EventMessage $event) use (&$Connected) {
    if ($event instanceof HangupEvent) {
        // Received Hangup Event - let terminate this while loop ..
        $Connected = 0;
     }
});
```

Comment: Actually it should be `use (&$Connected)`, since (s)he wants to modify the value.

Comment: Correct @FelixKling, changed answer

Answer (score 1):

As the others said and as it is [shown in the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php), in order to modify the value of the variable inside the closure, you have to pass it using `use (&$Conntected)`. But you have to change more than that.

The `while` loop will be executed until `$Connected` is `1`, that means you end up adding many many event handlers to the client... this is not what you want though.

Now, I don't know how PHP handels these event callbacks (or concurrent function calls), but I think what you need is [`sleep`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sleep.php):

```
$Client->EventListener(function (EventMessage $event) use (&$Conntected) {
    if ($event instanceof HangupEvent) {
        // Received Hangup Event - let terminate this while loop ..
        $Connected = false;
     }
});

while($Connected) {
    sleep(500); // delay execution for 500 milliseconds, then check again
}
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP handles closures differently than other languages do. You have do specifically declare which variables to close. You can read about it here: http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php

Try $Client->EventListener(function(EventMessage $event) use (&$Connected) {